# MIME::Lite - Mail to multiple recipients

Tags: perl, email, smtp, postfix-mta

I am trying to add multiple recipient in cc to my mail api but it gives me the following error:
SMTP recipient() command failed:
5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
My code is :

```
sub send_email{
        my $SE = shift;
        my $Mgr = shift;
        my $message = shift;
        my $TEAM_email = shift;
        my @cc=($Mgr,$TEAM_email);
        $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => 'abs@xyz.com',
                 To       => $SE,
                 Cc       => \@cc,
                 Subject  => 'Greetings of Day',
                 Data     => $message
                 );

$msg->send('smtp',$SmtpServer);
}
```

What is the problem? WHhy it is not working?

Comment: This is fairly straightforward. You're running on a Postfix server, and at least one of the email addresses you've specified is on the local domain but the server doesn't know the user name.

Comment: Have you tried to debug/trace SMTP session?  `$msg->send('smtp',$SmtpServer,Debug=>1);` - it should produce SMTP session trace via STDERR (standard error stream).

Comment: Looks like `Cc` expects a comma-separated string, not an array reference.

Comment: (Although [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT) also recommend using a different module.)