# People in cc are not receiving the mail using MIME::Lite api

Tags: perl

Please find below my code snippet that send a mail to person and his friend in cc.
In the cc list I also have a DL.

```
use MIME::Lite;

$to = 'ABC@DOMAIN1.com';
$from = 'MAILER@DOMAIN2.com';
$subject = 'How are you doing';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';
my @cc=('XYZ@DOMAIN2.com','DL@DOMAIN2.com');
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Cc       =>\@cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Data     => $message
                 );

$msg->send('smtp','smtpserver', Timeout => 60 );
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

The problem is the person and DL is cc are not receiving the mails.
Is there any log in the api MIME::Lite where I can check what is the error(if any)Or what do you think the problem can be?

Comment: Obligatory FYI...the `MIME::Lite` [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT) say: "**WAIT!** MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."

Comment: Also, please do not re-post the [exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28771137/176646) multiple times. You clearly didn't follow the advice in [Jim Davis's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771137/mimelite-mail-to-multiple-recipients#comment45827954_28771137) on your previous question about `Cc` taking a string instead of an arrayref.

Comment: Actually ending with `$msg->print` instead of `send(...)` will reveal 2 `Cc:` fields (1 for each value in array). I'm not sure if multiple CC's conform to e-mail RFC, let alone implementations.

Comment: Please `use strict; use warnings;` in the beginning of your script (you'll also need to declare your variables using `my` when you do so). It's 2015!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to take a closer look at [the documentation for MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite). Here's the first example from the synopsis.

```
use MIME::Lite;
### Create a new single-part message, to send a GIF file:
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From     => 'me@myhost.com',
    To       => 'you@yourhost.com',
    Cc       => 'some@other.com, some@more.com',
    Subject  => 'Helloooooo, nurse!',
    Type     => 'image/gif',
    Encoding => 'base64',
    Path     => 'hellonurse.gif'
);
$msg->send; # send via default
```

The `Cc` parameter here is sent as a text string containing comma-separated email addresses. You are passing in a reference to an array of email addresses.